# Is there a way to select results after a certain id in an order list?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sorting, pagination

I'm trying to implement a cursor-based paginating list based off of data from a Postgres database.

As an example, say I have a table with the following columns:

`id | firstname | lastname`

I want to paginate this data, which would be pretty simple if I only ever wanted to sort it by the id, but in my case, I want the option to sort by last name, and there's guaranteed to be multiple people with the same last name.

If I have a select statement like follows:

```
SELECT * FROM people
ORDER BY lastname ASC;
```

In the case, I could make my encoded cursor contain information about the `lastname` so I could pick up where I left off, but since there will be multiple users with the same last name, this will be buggy. Is there a way in SQL to only get the results after a certain id in an ordered list where it is not the column by which the results are sorted?

Example results from the select statement:

```
1 | John  | Doe
4 | John  | Price
2 | Joe   | White
6 | Jim   | White
3 | Sam   | White
5 | Sally | Young
```

If I wanted a page size of 3, I couldn't add `WHERE lastname <= :lastname` as I'd have duplicate data on the list since it would return ids 2, 6, and 3 during that call. In my case, it'd be helpful if I could add to my query something similar to `AFTER id = 6` where it could skip everything until it finds that `id` in the ordered list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  If I understand correctly:

```
select t.*
from t
where (lastname, id) > (select t2.lastname, t2.id
                        from t t2
                        where t2.id = ?
                       )
order by t.lastname;
```

I think I would add `firstname` into the mix, but it is the same idea.

Answer (score 0):

Limit and offset are used for pagination e.g.:

`SELECT id, lastname, firstname FROM people
Order by lastname, firstname, id
Offset 0
Limit 10`

This will bring you the first to the 10th row, to retrieve the next page you need to specify the offset to 10

Here the documentation:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/queries-limit.html

Comment: Unfortunately that wouldn't work in my case. I have too much dynamic data which makes using limit and offset too error prone.

Comment: I understand, and if your table will have many rows I'll prefer to pass the three values (lastname, firstname, id) than a subselect, It'll be less expensive to execute